# Displaying GUI Issue

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to display a gui but cannot get the frame to show here is the code so far:

The idea behind this is that the string path (which is the path to an image) is calculated in another class, it is then passed to this class where the image is to be displayed.

I cannot get the frame to be displayed, my usual method would be:

new displayWindow();

but this does not work.

What would be the best method of displaying the gui?

```
public class displayWindow {

    public displayWindow(String path) {

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(speed);
        label.setIcon(icon);
        label.setText(path);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);    
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Speed Limit");
        frame.setSize(500, 500); 
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println(path);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());            
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(430, 430);           
        frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);    
        frame.repaint();            
    }

    public static void displayWindow() {    
        new displayWindow();    
    }    
}
```

Comment: frame.setVisible(true); to the end (instead of repaint)?

Comment: is there a reason that you set layout 2 times? border and then flow layout? call `setVisible` at the end.

Comment: _Pleeese_ take a look at [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: IntelliJ still wont let me run it.

Comment: What's `speed` supposed to be?

Comment: And use Java naming convention. Classes start with upper case lettering. Also don't name your method same as your class/constructor.

Comment: Overall, this code is bogus. Do yourself a favor: start the tutorial from the beginning

Answer (score 4):

With the code you provide, your code even compile cause you don't have a default constructor with no args. Your constructor takes one parameter.

So your method should be:

```
public static void displayWindow(String param) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            new displayWindow(param);
        }

    });    
}
```

Using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..)` you ensure that will run in the `EDT`(Event Dispatch Thread.)

Is there a reason for this?

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.setSize(430, 430);
```

In java by convention  class names starts with upperCase so you class should be called `DisplayWindow` this is very important for readability.

And call `setVisible(true)` after you add components to your frame :)

Comment: Would Java even create a default constructor in this case? I thought that constructor was only made if the programmer didn't supply any other constructors.

Comment: @PakkuDon `Would Java even create a default constructor in this case?` No, he writes a constructor with one argument, then he must specify default constructor with no args if he want to use.